# Android - Recreating an acivity - Bundle

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here is the code for recreating an activity.

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Here,I have a doubt in the definition of putInt() method of bundle. When I looked for its definition, I got the following documentation -

> public void putInt (String key, int value)
>  Added in API level
>   1
>  Inserts an int value into the mapping of this Bundle, replacing
>   any existing value for the given key. Parameters
>  key:    a String,
>   or null
>  value:   an int, or null

I don't understand what is being done with the String key ? I mean to say, is it like that. that every time key is used as a pointer to add matter to the bundle ? Moreover, is there any need of defining STATE_SCORE as "playerscore" ?

Comment: you need to first call the super()

Comment: @meh how can i call super() first without adding elements to the bundle ?

Comment: what I meant was that you must call the     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
method first before adding anything to the bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bundle` works like a dictionary. In a dictionary you use a keyword to look for a meaning (or definition). That's the purpose of the `String`. `Bundle` use it to retrive the value linked to that key.

> Moreover, is there any need of defining STATE_SCORE as "playerscore"

that's not strictly neccessary, but if you declare a constant for your keys, and use always the costant to store/retrieve values from bundle the probability of mispelling decrease near to zero (so more headcache due of intesive debuggin hours)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will be done to your string key. It is just like a hash map. I don't quite understand your last question, it is good manner to define the key as a constant.

Comment: Actually I was asking whether I need to define it particularly by playerscore  or it is not necessary ?

Comment: Now I understand it is not necessary to define it like that

Answer (score 0):

is there any need of defining STATE_SCORE as "playerscore". Ans is NO you can directly give the string

```
savedInstanceState.putInt("playerscore", mCurrentScore);
```

I don't understand what is being done with the String key

it is like a key value pair. when you do this

```
 savedInstanceState.putInt("playerscore", 1);
```

the value 1 is stores with the key "playerscore" and when you do a get

```
savedInstanceState.getInt("playerscore");
```

This will return 1